# WordPress in OpenShift Origin using the official example

Tags: openshift-origin

I've installed `All-In-One OpenShift Origin Virtual Machine (Version 1.1.6)` and deployed WordPress by following the instruction given in [origin/examples/wordpress](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/wordpress).
I've chosen [NFS storage](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/wordpress/nfs/README.md)

I need to know:

1. When I `ls` in to `/home/data/pv0002` it show MySQL files as expected. But when I `ls` in to the `/home/data/pv0001` it shows nothing! isn't the WordPress files have to be there?
2. When I try to upload media in WordPress it show an error message like below

   `Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`

   What do I have to do to fix this?
3. When I try to install new theme it asks for ftp credentials. What do I have to do to get that?

Log from POD

```
warning: both WORDPRESS_DB_HOST and MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP found
  Connecting to WORDPRESS_DB_HOST (mysql)
  instead of the linked mysql container
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
WARNING: /var/www/html is not empty - press Ctrl+C now if this is an error!
+ ls -A
+ sleep 10
.htaccess
tar: ./index.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./license.txt: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./readme.html: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-activate.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/about.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/admin-footer.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/admin-functions.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/admin-header.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/admin-post.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-admin/admin.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted

...

tar: ./xmlrpc.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot change mode to rwxr-xr-x: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: What do the openshift logs tell you on the pv mounts, can you share exactly what you see when you get the request for NFS credentials?

Comment: @EricRich I've added the log from pod

Comment: @Balakrishnan what are the permissions and owners of your folder (in which you mount your content)?. Not sure if its related but you can try. E.g. it's /var/export/logs: chown nfsnobody:nfsnobody /var/export/regvol and chmod 777 /var/export/regvol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Centos 7 I did the following steps and everything worked perfectly. Important steps are **3**, **4** and **5**. And there is no need to edit the restricted scc to RunAsAny.

**Step 1:**

```
# systemctl status docker
# systemctl status nfs
```

**Step 2:**
start cluster

**Step 3:**

```
# mkdir -p /home/data/pv0001
# mkdir -p /home/data/pv0002
# chmod -R 777 /home/data/
# chown -R nfsnobody:nfsnobody /home/data/
```

**Step 4:**

```
# cat /etc/exports
/home/data/pv0001 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/home/data/pv0002 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)

# exportfs -a
# setsebool -P virt_use_nfs 1
```

**Step 5:**
and from wordpress project as `system:admin`

```
# oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
```

which means allow the containers in this project to run as root.

**Step 6:**
deploy wordpress